# How to output a checkbox group to email in hard code

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a form, that has 2 sections where you can select multiple checkboxes and I have not figured out how to get those checkboxes to show up in the email. Here is what the checkboxes look like on the form: [image]

I have the locations and characteristics saved in a checkbox group in the back in of Freeform Pro. There is a label and value assigned to each option. My code looks like this:

```
                                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;"><b>Location Preference (check all that apply)</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Great Bend </label><input name="great_bend" value="Great Bend" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="great_bend"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Hays </label><input name="hays" value="Hays" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="hays"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>McPherson </label><input name="mcpherson" value="McPherson" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="mcpherson"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Hutchinson </label><input name="hutchinson" value="Hutchinson" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="hutchinson"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Colby </lable><input name="colby" value="Colby" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="colby"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Wichita </lable><input name="wichita" value="Witchita" name="support[]" type="checkbox" id="wichita"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">Desired Characteristics of Your IDEAL Firm<br /><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .9em;">Please check your top three characteristics</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Compensation and benefits </label><input name="benefits" value="benefits" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="benefits"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Networking / Future job opportunities </label><input name="networking" value="networking" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="networking"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Client Size </label><input name="client_size" value="client_size" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="client_size"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Firm Location </label><input name="location" value="locations" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="location2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Opportunity for travel </label><input name="travel" value="travel" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="travel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Experience in variety of industries </label><input name="experience" value="experience" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="experience"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Opportunities for internal advancement </label><input name="advancement" value="advancement" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox" id="advancement"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left" width="300" bgcolor="#efeff0"><label>Work / Life balance </label><input name="balance" value="balance" name="idea_characteristics[]" type="checkbox"></td>                 
                </tr>
```

I tired a few different things as you can see in the code. But, so far nothing has worked. How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure {idea_characteristics} is also in your email notification template.

Comment: I have the following in my email notification template: Desired Characteristics of Your Ideal Firm: {idea_characteristics}

Comment: Confirm also that your form tag is set to use that notification template.

Comment: Are you using the paid version of Freeform Pro?

Comment: Also, post your opening form tag in your code above.

Comment: Yes, I am using the paid version of Freeform Pro. My opening form tag is this: {exp:freeform:form form:class="employment_form" collection="Employment Form" recipients="yes"  return="employment-form/employee_submission" template="employment_form"}

Comment: template="" is not a valid parameter. Check the docs for what to use: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/

Comment: I have checked that my form is set to use that notification template. Everything else in the form works fine, this is my only issue with the form that is not working correctly.

Comment: I've taken out the template="" param, still nothing is showing up in the test email.

Comment: Add this into your email template "HELLO WORLD". Then retest the form to make sure that FreeForm is indeed using the correct notification template.

Comment: I ran that test and it is using the correct template.

Comment: @Solspace is there a certain tag that I need to do this?

Comment: The issue is surely in the code or setup... So I'd suggest starting from scratch... Set up a new form and just add the checkbox field until you get that working. Then add it back into your main form. Start with just one checkbox field too so you have the bare minimum.

Comment: The collection="" parameter has been changed in Freeform 4=Pro, use form_name="Employment Form" instead. Not sure if that will fix it but worth checking! Full list of version 4 changed tags at http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/upgrade_3.x-4.x/ so a good idea to make sure your form tag uses the latest parameter names.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl ok thanks, I'll try and trouble shoot that way.

Comment: @Bluedreamer thanks for the link. I'm looking at the doc changes now. I really appreciate the help with this.